# Who to create web service for windows push notification for windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

While working with Windows Phone Push Notifications, I got myself stuck in the part of creating the "cloud web service" to receive the negotiated URL and retrieve updates to the mobile device.Is it possible to create this Web Service without using Windows Azure services (I don't want to pay anything, I just want to push with my services to my apps)? And how can I create this Cloud Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked extensively with Windows Phone 8.1. Check this webpage for Windows Phone 8 -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202970%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

You will get a URL for each device you want to get notification on through the app you create. Taking help from the above link, you can create a local server (Cloud Web Service) for testing push notifications for your test devices.

Comment: We need for hybrid app not for native app

Comment: @Nani I haven't worked with hybrid apps. But I'm guessing some code must be native even in a hybrid app??